# Weird symbols or not loaded symbols with synth-shell on terminal

Tags: command-line, customization, github

It was fine until I reinstalled Linux. I also tried to reinstall it, but nothing changed.
I cloned it and followed the instruction from [GitHub](https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell).

[image: terminal screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with `sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline`[image: terminal screenshot]